# symfony 1.4 and Apache access/error logs

Tags: apache, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Symfony 1.4 is set up as the only virtual host in my Apache config. Should I make use of the Apache access logs and error logs or does symfony take care of both of these for me?

Answer (score 1):

Apache logs are not the same as the logging provided by symfony. Apache logs are useful for other reasons than symfony's. I usually use the following virtual host config for my local development.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName dev.yoursite.com.br

  DocumentRoot "/home/you/dev/sfprojects/yoursite/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory "/home/you/dev/sfprojects/yoursite/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/you/dev/sfprojects/yoursite/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/you/dev/sfprojects/yoursite/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/home/you/dev/sfprojects/yoursite/log/error.log"
  CustomLog "/home/you/dev/sfprojects/yoursite/log/web.log" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

For symfony, I configure the factories.yml like the following

```
dev:
  logger:
    class:   sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level:   notice
      loggers:
        sf_file_err:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: err
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%_error.log
        sf_file_notice:
          class: sfFileLogger
          param:
            level: notice
            file: %SF_LOG_DIR%/%SF_APP%_%SF_ENVIRONMENT%_notice.log
```

Comment: I also find it useful to use `sfFileLogger` with the `err` level in production.